# Separating several kinds of information in a sound file

Tags: filters, python, voice

I have a 90min audio recording of a lecture using a handheld recorder. Since the recorder was in the shirt pocket of the speaker, I can clearly hear that the their voice is much louder than the audience. Occasionally a question is asked by the audience and we can hear their voice, but we can't really understand it because it is so much softer.

Here's a sample:

[image]

I would like to detect three modes: speaker alone; audience member alone; and overlapping voices. One would think that filtering simply by the loudness would get us a long way there. I am a programmer and could build something in python or whatnot but I don't want to reinvent the wheel. I am looking for a pointer, hint, link, tool, or whatever!

Comment: Could you load 1-2 snippets of each mode into Audacity then post screenshots of the waveforms? That could give us a better idea of what these signals look like.

Comment: I updated the question... Does that help?

Comment: Your problem seems to be related to [blind source separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_separation). [Here](https://github.com/nussl/nussl) is a python package that tries to solve this problem. I haven't personally used it.